# Unable to connect to the Wi-Fi when App is running under Work profile on Samsung device having Android 10

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, samsung-mobile, samsung-knox

We have one internal Android application that we are deploying through intune on the `Work Profile` side. When the App is running on Samsung Device with `Android 10` then in that case we are not able to connect to the intended Wi-Fi however when the same app is installed on a `Personal Profile`, we are able to connect to the Wi-Fi. Strange this is that when we tested this on a `Samsung` device running on `Android 9` and in that it worked on both personal and work profile side without any issue.

As `Samsung` has not officially rolled out `Android 11` we were not able to test it but we did test this on `Pixel` device with `Android 11` and in that also it's working fine on the Work profile side.

Below is the code that we are using for Wi-Fi connectivity:

```
public bool EnableWifi(string ssid, string password)
        {
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration
            {
                Ssid = string.Format("\"{0}\"", ssid),
            };


            wifiConfig.PreSharedKey = string.Format("\"{0}\"", password);

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

            wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);

            netId = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);

            wifiManager.DisableNetwork(netId);

            var result = wifiManager.EnableNetwork(netId, true);

            wifiManager.Reconnect();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Can you connect from Android without the application?  What operating System are you using?

Comment: Yes, I can directly connect to the Wi-Fi without the app but not through the App. Am using Android 10

Comment: I meant the kernel.  May need updates.  See : https://github.com/djb77/samsung-kernel